# Get all registered wp theme customizer sections?

Tags: theme-customizer

Is there a way to retrieve all the registered customizer sections? I'm building out a custom customizer and don't want other plugin or themes who register custom sections to appear on this page.

I can remove all the default sections, but I can't predict which plugins or themes will register sections.

`$wp_customize->remove_section( 'title_tagline' );`

removes the default title_tagline section.

I can see all of the registered sections by doing `print_r( $wp_customize );`. I would just loop over that section and build an array to un-register, but I can't seem to access the array of registered sections due to it being protected.

Is there any other way to retreive registered sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around inside of some core files, I was actually able to get this resolved.

The following function will retrieve all registered sections in the customizer and loop over each to un-register them altogether.

This should run before registering any of your own custom sections, as to not remove your custom registered sections.

```
function eherman_remove_registered_customizer_sections() {
    // retrieve the sections array
    $registered_sections = $wp_customize->sections();
    // loop over and remove each section
    foreach( $registered_sections as $section ) {
       $wp_customize->remove_section( $section->id );
    }   
}
```

Not bad at all. Hopefully that helps others out as we move closer to a more powerful customizer!

**Resources:**

- [WP Customizer Class](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L401)

Comment: Alternative helpful is the filter `customize_control_active`, small example here https://github.com/bueltge/customizer-sandbox/blob/master/inc/remove-defaults.php

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `sections` method? You can use `$wp_customize->sections()`.

Example:

```
foreach ($wp_customize->sections() as $section_key => $section_object ) {
  echo $section_key . '<br />';
}
```